# Is there an internet free radio app that can connect to bluetooth speakers

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, fm-radio

I have an old Samsung galaxy S1 that I would like to use an a radio transmitter and connect to my home entertainment system via bluetooth.

To run the built in app you are required to have head phones connected and you have the option to output the music through the phone speaker.

How can I move this from the phone speaker to the bluetooth option?

Are there any apps that can do this?

The main criteria for this is to be internet free. If the internet is required I can just use the laptop for the music through Spotify or some other app(which i don't want to do)

Comment: So you're wanting to use the onboard FM receiver to play music through bluetooth?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Either through the default application or if needed i will download another app